# Custom elements with proxied has, get & set

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, web-component, es6-class, es6-proxy

My goal is to create a class `ObservableElement` extending `HTMLElement` such that it can be used to define custom elements, e g:

```
customElements.define('an-observable-elem', class extends ObservableElement {
  construct() {
    super()
    ...
  }
  ...
})
```

The thing about any element based on `ObservableElement` is that it should have some particular behaviours wrt to properties.

First, `'whatever' in myElem` should *always* be true. In other words, I'd like a proxy trap for `has` on the instance, which just always returns true.

Second, setting and getting any props should work. But whenever a prop which is not explicitly defined on the element or in the prototype chain is set, I want to emit a custom event with the name `set${propname}` and `detail: theValue`.

It seems there must be a way using es6-proxies. Naively, I first tried:

```
class ObservableElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor () {
    super()
    const vals = {}
    return Proxy(this, {
      has: _ => true,
      get: name => {
        if (name in this) return this[name]
        if (name in vals) return vals[name]
        return null
      },
      set: (name, value) => {
        if (name in this) {
          this[name] = value
          return
        }
        if (vals[name] === value) return
        vals[name] = value
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(`set${name}`, {detail: value}))
      }
    })
  }
}
```

But of course that didn't work. Returning the proxy from the constructor did not change the `this` value in extending classes' constructors. I fumbled around with all sorts of combinations of proxying `construct` on the class, `Object.setPrototypeOf(...)` et c to no avail.

I'd much appreciate it if anyone who understands how these things can fit together to achieve what I want would explain it to me. Thanks!

Comment: Your proxy handlers are missing the `target` parameter, so you're using the wrong values.

Comment: By the way, I fixed your example and tried it myself. You cannot override the `constructor` by returning a different object than `this` or you get the error `Uncaught DOMException: custom element constructors must call super() first and must not return a different object`, so encapsulating the class instance with a `Proxy` is impossible.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts thanks! You're right, the traps need the target parameter, but that's not the problem I was running into -- but rather the second problem you mentioned.

However I don't yet believe it's completely impossible to add proxy traps to an instance being constructed. You can proxy the class itself, and the `construct` property. I just can't figure out how to put the pieces together...

Comment: There isn't a trick here. The web component API is designed in such a way that only instances that extend the `HTMLElement` class will be inserted into the DOM. A `Proxy` is an exotic object that has no intrinsic `prototype` (its "prototype" is inherited from the object it encapsulates) so the DOM will not accept it as an instance of `HTMLElement`.

Comment: I see. that's a pity. Any other ideas how to achieve the goal of having a custom element that can trigger an event on any property assignment (and will act as if it has any property)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### What you're trying to do is not supported by the W3C Web Components specification.

[According to §2.4 of the W3C Web Components specification, step 10.6.2](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#the-customelementregistry-interface):

> If `observedAttributesIterable` is not `undefined`, then set `observedAttributes` to the result of converting `observedAttributesIterable` to a `sequence<DOMString>`. Rethrow any exceptions from the conversion.

This occurs during the [`customElements.define()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomElementRegistry/define) execution, which means that you'd have to define an iterable of every conceivable string when the class is defined in order to intercept all attribute changes.

If the component does not find the changed property in that sequence, it does not call the [`attributeChangedCallback()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements#Using_the_lifecycle_callbacks).

Similarly it is impossible to return a proxy from the `constructor` because of [the restriction in §2.2](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#requirements-for-custom-element-constructors):

> A `return` statement must not appear anywhere inside the constructor body, unless it is a simple early-return (`return` or `return this`).

Comment: Thanks for the solid, well referenced explanation!